# poisson process probability nobody uses a gift card

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Hi there i have a fun problem. It is a Poisson process about gift cards and the following chances are given:

P(Card purchased on $t_0$ and has not yet been used by day $t_1$) = $e^{\frac{-p}{q}(1-e^{-q(t_1-t_0)})}$

$P_{0}(\tau) = e^{-\int_0^{\tau} p(s)ds}$ where $p(s) = pe^{-qs}$

This chance is the chance that the card is not used before day $\tau$.

So i thought i simplistically just multiply these chances to get the chance that, a card purchased on $t_0$ and not yet used by day $t_1$, will never be used. However in my answer sheet i get the answer

P(Never) =  $e^{\frac{−p}{q}(e^{−q(t_1−t_0)})}$.

Is there something i missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(\text{never used}\mid\text{unused by time }t_1)\\
=P(\text{never used and unused by time }t_1)/P(\text{unused by time }t_1)\\
=P(\text{never used})/P(\text{unused by time }t_1)\\
=(\lim_{t_1\to\infty}e^{-(p/q)(1-e^{-q(t_1-t_0)})})/e^{-(p/q)(1-e^{-q(t_1-t_0)})}\\
=e^{-p/q}/e^{-(p/q)(1-e^{-q(t_1-t_0)})}\\
=e^{-(p/q)(e^{-q(t_1-t_0)})}
$$

Comment: i think you used bayes theorem:

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A) \cdot P(A)}{P(B)}$

And i understand that the left hand side and the denominator. But how is $P(\text{Unused by time t_1|never used})*P(\text{never used}) = P(\text{never used})$?

Comment: do you agree that $P(B\mid A)P(A)=P(A\text{ and }B)$?

Comment: yes that is true :D

Comment: and that if $A\subset B$, then $P(A\text{ and }B)=P(A)$?

Comment: yes obviously, but unused by time $t_1$ is a subset of never used right...?

Comment: other way around--never used implies unused by time $t_1$